# Generic while loop through mysql query result

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I'm wondering if there's a way - using php - to loop through a mysqli query result and display the column name, and the data... so,

Name => Joe Bloggs,
Age => 23

effectively allowing me to change the query, without having to echo out each row individually.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.... `foreach($sql as $row)` pretty much does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the column names by fetching the result rows 'associatively':

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'dbname');

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Name, Age FROM user");

while (($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) !== null) {
    $output = array();
    foreach ($row as $columnName => $columnValue) {
        $output[] = $columnName . ' => ' . $columnValue;
    }
    echo implode(', ', $output) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Would output something like:

```
Name => Joe Bloggs, Age => 23
Name => Another User, Age => 5
```

if you have two users in the user table.

Comment: Somehow you understood my poor description... This is exactly what I was after, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean. Then only way I understand your question (that makes sense to me) is to suggest you use "fetch_assoc" to iterate over your result set in order to gain easy access to the column names with which you can do as you please from then on. Maybe the "using php" is tripping me over.